# Why does the voltage of a solar panel change as the tilt angle changes?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electric-current, voltage, solar-cells

I performed an experiment where I linked a solar panel to a constant resistance, and took readings of the voltage and current every 10 minutes between 11:00 and 18:00.  I performed this for 0,  π/6,  π/3, and  π/2 radians at the same time every day. The temperature and wind were roughly the same for each setup.

I noticed that I got an inverted parabolic curve when I graphed the average voltage for each tilt angle vs the tilt angle. However, my teacher said that the voltage should be constant, while the graph of current should be an inverted parabola. My graph of current vs tilt angle is an inverted parabola, but my voltage isn't constant.

In ideal theoretical conditions, should voltage change as tilt angle changes? Why or why not?

Comment: if your resistor was not very high, you measured a mixture of current and voltage. the voltage breaks down if the current is ti high, so try the same with a much larger resistor or even with only the resistor of your voltmeter.

Comment: google solar flux

Comment: @trula I did try it using higher resistances too after consulting my teacher, but the voltage curve still remained an inverted parabola.

Comment: @DavidWhite I know what solar flux is, but as I understand it, it does not significantly affect the voltage (given that there is enough solar flux for voltage to reach its maximum value). Can you please elaborate?